# Why are minhook library directories non existant

Tags: c++, linker, nuget

I installed the latest MinHook from NuGet and I get this error, My friend also used MinHook on his project and he got the same error. I am kinda new to C++ so maybe this sounds dumb. Also I check the directory and the files don't exist. There is another lib folder with Libraries but Visual Studio seems to ignore it. This is the error that shows up all the time during building

`Error LNK1104:  cannot open file 'C:\Users\<my name>\source\repos\<project name>\packages\minhook.1.3.3\build\native\..\..\lib\native\lib\libMinHook.lib'`

Here is my pragma: `#pragma comment(lib, "libMinHook.x86.lib")`
I took this exact line from the MinHook documentation, And my project is set to x86

I have searched the internet but to no avail. Sorry if this is a dumb question, like I said, I am new to C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue today. Here is what you need to do:

1. Copy file MinHook.x86.lib to your project's folder
2. Go to Project properties > Linker > Input > Additional dependencies
3. Type "MinHook.x86.lib" in Additional dependencies window
4. Go back to your code and adjust it like this:

   `#if defined _M_X64 #pragma comment(lib, "MinHook.x64.lib") #elif defined _M_IX86 #pragma comment(lib, "MinHook.x86.lib") #endif`
5. Now you can do the same for MinHook.x64.lib if you want.

Answer (score 1):

that was a while ago, my issue was I wasn't setting the Additional Libraries Directory in linker settings

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had MSVC v142 installed, but the nuget package only supported v141